# Mysql : How to know the value of a field at date (audit table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table CONTACT with a field opt_out.

The field opt_out may have values 'Y', 'N' and NULL.

I have a table CONTACT_AUDIT with fields

```
date
contact_id
field_name
value_before
value_after
```

When I add a new contact, a new line is added in the CONTACT table, nothing the CONTACT_AUDIT table.

When I edit a contact, for example if I change the opt_out field value from NULL to 'Y', the opt_out field value in CONTACT table is changed and a new line is added to CONTACT_AUDIT table with values

```
date=NOW()
contact_id=<my contact's id>
field_name='opt_out'
value_before=NULL
value_after='Y'
```

I need to know the contacts who had opt_out='Y' at a given date.

I tried this :

```
SELECT count(*) AS nb
FROM contacts c
WHERE
( -- contact is optout now and has never been modified before
    c.optout = 'Y'
    AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM contacts_audit WHERE field_name =     'optout')
)
OR ( -- we consider contacts where the last row before date in contacts_audit is     optout = 'Y'
    c.id IN (
      SELECT ca.contact_id
      FROM contacts_audit ca
      WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-07-24' AND DATE_ADD( '2014-07-24', INTERVAL 1 DAY )
      AND field_name = 'optout'
      ORDER BY date_created
      LIMIT 1
    )
)
```

But mysql does not support LIMIT in subquery.

So I tried with HAVING :

```
SELECT count(*) AS nb
FROM contacts c
WHERE
( -- contact is optout now and has never been modified before
    c.optout = 'Y'
    AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM contacts_audit WHERE field_name =     'optout')
)
OR ( -- we consider contacts where the last row before date in contacts_audit is     optout = 'Y'
    c.id IN (
      SELECT ca.contact_id
      FROM contacts_audit ca
      WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-07-24' AND DATE_ADD( '2014-07-24', INTERVAL 1 DAY )
      AND field_name = 'optout'
      HAVING MAX(date_created)
    )
)
```

The query runs, but now, I don't know how to know if the value corresponding to the subquery value is 'Y' or 'N'. If I add a WHERE clause to check only for 'Y' values, 'N' values will be filtred and I will not be able to know if the last value at date was 'Y' or 'N'...

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't get it. Why is the last value important. I thought you want to know if it was Yes at any time in the interval. What has MAX(date) to do with it?

Comment: @juergend : If the value has become 'y' at 2014-06-12 and 'n' at 2014-06-13, I need the last one before 2014-06-15 to know the value at 2014-06-15 for example.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you may want to use a union. I dont have mysql to test it right now but the code could be something like this. tell me if this helped

```
select c.id, c.optout 
where c.optout = 'Y'
AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM contacts_audit WHERE field_name =          'optout')
UNION
select c.id, c.optout where c.id IN (
  SELECT ca.contact_id
  FROM contacts_audit ca
  WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-07-24' AND DATE_ADD( '2014-07-24', INTERVAL 1 DAY )
  AND field_name = 'optout'
  HAVING MAX(date_created)
)
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think it is correct. With your query, I get

* all the contacts that exist in database now (I should add a clause to filter those who were not created yet at given date) and have never been modified, with their actual (and past if it has never been modified) value for the wanted field

* and all the contacts with the value of the wanted field at the given date.

But what I need is to get all the contacts where optout was 'y' at the given date.

So we need to filter by value in the second query but I don't know to do that filter and get also the last row from contact_audit

Comment: ok i hope i understand more this time. Why in your subquery you dont do something like this OR ( -- we consider contacts where the last row before date in contacts_audit is     optout = 'Y'
    c.id IN (
select ca.contact_id from (
      SELECT ca.contact_id, value_after
      FROM contacts_audit ca
      WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-07-24' AND DATE_ADD( '2014-07-24', INTERVAL 1 DAY )
      AND field_name = 'optout'
      HAVING MAX(date_created)
 ) bb where bb.value_after='Y'
    )
)